# Covariance between two binomial random variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, binomial-distribution, covariance

Consider a binomial random variable $X$ with parameter $p$ and another binomial random variable $Y$ with parameter $q$. What is the covariance of $X$ and $Y$?

How well does the proof generalize to $n$ such random variables $X_1...X_n$ with respective parameters $p_1...p_n$? Has the covariance matrix been worked out in this case as well?

Comment: Binomial distribution or Bernoulli distribution? If binomial, $n$ is needed. My answer is based on Bernoulli, If you mean Binomial, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the binomial random variable are independent, then of course the population correlation is $0.$ Samples from the distributions of the two random variables will tend to be near $0.$

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rbinom(10^5, 10, .3);  y = rbinom(10^5, 10, .7)
cor(x,y)
[1] -0.0006200541
```

However, one can simulate mixtures of binomial random variables that are correlated.
In the plot below, a small amount of uniform noise keeps points that would
have had exactly integer coordinates from plotting exactly on top of each
other. [This is called 'jittering'.]

```
set.seed(2019)
p = rbeta(10^4, 2, 2)  # different p's for each (x,y)-pair below
x = rbinom(10^4, 10, p);  y = rbinom(10^4, 10, p)
cor(x, y)
[1] 0.7146091
cov(x,y)
[1] 5.03711
X = x + runif(10^4, -.2, .2)
Y = y + runif(10^4, -.2, .2)
plot(X, Y, pch=".")
```

[image]

Finally, if the success probabilities $p$ are the same in three
independent binomials $U, V,$ and $W,$ each distributed 
$\mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p = 0.3),$ then $X = U+V$ and $Y = U+W$ are
correlated random variables, each with distribution
$\mathsf{Binom}(10, 0.3).$ Also,

$$Cov(X,Y) = Cov(U+V, U+W) = Cov(U,U)\\ = Var(U) = 5p(1-p) = 1.05,$$
where the second inequality is due to the mutual independence of $U,V,$ and $W.$

```
set.seed(713);  m = 30000
u = rbinom(m, 5, .3);  v = rbinom(m, 5, .3);  w = rbinom(m, 5, .3)
x = u + v;  y = u + w
cor(x, y);  cov(x, y)
[1] 0.5082363
[1] 1.065182   # aprx Cov(X,Y) = 1.05

par(mfrow=c(1,3));  cutp = (-1:10)+.5
k = 0:10;  pdf = dbinom(k, 10, .3)
 hist(x, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
  points(k, pdf, col="red", pch=19)
 hist(y, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
  points(k, pdf, col="red", pch=19)
X = x + runif(m, -.2, .2)
Y = y + runif(m, -.2, .2)
 plot(X,Y, pch=".")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The first two panels show histograms of simulated marginal distributions
of $X$ and $Y,$ with red dots showing exact PDFs. The simulated marginal distribution is shown (slightly jittered) in the third panel.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the values for $X$ and $Y$ following Bernoulli distribution are 0 and 1, and $p$ and $q$ are probabilities of being 1. We know $$Cov(Y,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$$ and $$E(X)E(Y)=pq.$$
Since $E(XY) = P(X\!=\!1,Y\!\!=\!1) = p\mu$, where $\mu\!=\!P(Y\!\!=\!1|X\!=\!1)\!\in\![0,1]$, we have
$$E(XY) \leq min(p,q)$$
and since $P(X\!=\!1,Y\!\!=\!1) = q - \lambda(1-p)$, where $\lambda\!=\!P(Y=1|X=0)$
$$E(XY) \geq max(0,p+q-1).$$
So
$$max(0,p+q-1) - pq \le Cov(X,Y) \le min(p,q) -pq$$
For the situation of more than 2 random variables, it maybe is complicated.

Comment: Do you intend for $X$ and $Y$ to be _Bernoulli_ random variables?

Comment: Yes. May I misunderstand the OP. That no $N$s were given mislead me to bernouli. Maybe I should delete it.

Comment: No, please don't delete on account of my comment. Your interpretation is reasonable. But it is customary to say 'Bernoulli' when $n = 1,$ so I tried to make what sense I could of general Binomials with $n > 1.$ At least your interpretation led to an interesting answer (+1), I'm not sure I can say the same for mine.

Comment: If OP means binomial, my answer really does not answer the question.

Comment: It you wait for questions to be perfectly clear, there will be many fewer questions to answer. // Just browsed a few of your other answers. Some really nice ones there.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you. Here is something for you to kill the time.  a-statistician.github.io

Comment: May have a chance to check into that.